# Currently, data binding does not work for non-base feature modules. Please, move data binding code to the base feature module

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, android-architecture

I am following [Google Codelabs for instant app](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2017#5), and I was trying to create `topeka-ui` (An UI feature module for instant app).

It tells me to enable data binding like this for that UI module:

[image: instruction for data binding]

When I try to enable data binding inside the android block I get the following Error during gradle build.

```
Error:Currently, data binding does not work for non-base feature modules.
Please, move data binding code to the base feature module.
See https://issuetracker.google.com/63814741 for details
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: As of Android Studio 3.1 Canary, there is now an experimental option to bypass this gradle blocker for databinding, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63814741#comment21

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Mistake :** I was trying to **use data binding in non base feature module** *(As it was not explicitly mentioned in codelab)*

**Solution :** **paste** 
`baseFeature = true` **in android block** in the module where you are trying to use data binding.

Comment: How many baseFeature can an app have?
Because there's already a baseFeature = true declared in topeka-base

Comment: There can only be one base feature module

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the author doesn't answer his own question: **data binding doesn't work for non-base "feature modules"**...

Pasting `baseFeature = true` in android block of a secondary non-base feature will result in:

> "Error:Currently, data binding does not work for non-base features.
>   Move data binding code to the base feature module. See
>   https://issuetracker.google.com/63814741. To enable data binding with
>   non-base features, set the
>   android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding property to true."

So, **set the android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding property to true** in gradle properties.

Comment: When I set this property to true I got this:
> The option setting 'android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding=true' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'false'